# android videoView not play video file with japanese character

Tags: android, video-processing

I would like to play a video using the Android videoView. But I am unable to play the videos with file names with Japanese characters.

Does any one of you have faced the same problem and found any solution for the same?

Please Help me if Any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something related to your quetion . See if it can help
[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/lmpmf-dod5I)